# String in Folder Name in C++

Tags: c++

I want to name the folder according to the username given by the user. However, to do that (in the method in which I am doing), we have to enter the path of the folder including the name of the folder. I know the path, but, the name of the folder should be the username. The following is my code. Please help me! (Thanks for sharing your knowledge and time, in advance)

```
Path="Core\\USERS\\";
crtfol = Path + usrnm;
Sleep(10000);
CreateFolder(crtfol);
```

'usrnm' is a string for taking in  the username of the user.
'Path' is a string in which I have entered the path of the folder.
'crtfol' is also a string used to combine the path and the username.
'CreateFolder' is the fuction I am using to make folder.
In function CreateFolder, 'crtfol' is the name to be given to the folder.

**Error while compiling**:

> cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'void CreateFolder(const char*)'|

Compiling done in Codeblocks.

Thank You!

Comment: `CreateFolder(crtfol);` -> `CreateFolder(crtfol.c_str());`

Comment: Spamming tags is not a good way to make friends. Please limit the tags to the relevant ones.

Comment: BTW: what is the `Sleep(10000);` for?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: It's just to allow enough time for the computer to do the string concatenation, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
Path="Core\\USERS\\";
crtfol = Path + usrnm;
Sleep(10000);
CreateFolder(crtfol.c_str());
```

The function CreateFolder is not expecting a std::string as input parameter, but a C style string.

Comment: Thank You everyone! I tried some changes and guess what! Yes, it has worked. I am really vary happy, thank you guys